# How java @Value works?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, annotations

I used java @Value like this, it works fine, and the variable "baiduurl" can be resolved correctly:

```
package com.lanyyyy.springdemo.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.lanyyyy.springdemo.service.*;
@RestController
public class GetURL {
    @Value("${baiduurl}")
    public String baiduurl;

    @RequestMapping(path="/getbaidu", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getBaiduurl(){
//        return "hello";
        return baiduurl;
    }

}
```

======================

But when I use like this, the variabe "baiduurl" can not be resolved:

```
package com.lanyyyy.springdemo.service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class UrlService {
    @Value("${baiduurl}")
    public String baiduurl;

    //    @RequestMapping(path="/getbaidu", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getBaiduurl() {
        return baiduurl;
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong?????
Or I use the @Value wrong?????

In my applicaiton.properties:

```
baiduurl=http://www.baidu.com
server.port=8888
```

Answer (score 5):

When you annotated your controller as `@RestController` then your class will become a `@Controller`

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public @interface RestController
```

A `@Controller` annotated class is a `@Component`:

```
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Controller
```

During component scan, spring container will initialize your class, `@Autowire` fields and inject `@Value`

In your second example, your `UrlService` is not a bean so no binding/injecting is done.

You should mark your service with `@Service` (or other marker like `@Component`...) to have the spring container injected `baiduurl` value for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I got it:

If I want use "@Value", the class shuold be annotated by "@Component" or "@Service", then the class would be a bean and works fine